# jquery to update dropdown menu from textbox

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am new to jquery. I have a textbox, and I want to take value from a textbox and show it in dropdown menu. I have searched for the solution in many websites,but can't get an appropriate answer. Kindly please help me how to do it in jquery.

The code for textbox are shown below. Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english.

```
<form method="post" action="inq.php">
<p><br>
<b>Question no:</b><br>
  <input class="inp-form" type="Text" name="qno" size="30" required>
  <br>
<br>
  <b>Question:</b><br>
  <textarea  name="question" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
  <!--<input class="inp-form"type="Text" name="question" size="50">-->
  <br>
  <b>Option 1:</b><br>
  <input class="inp-form" type="Text" name="opt1" size="30" required>
  <br>
  <b>Option 2:</b><br>
  <input class="inp-form"type="Text" name="opt2" size="30" required>
  <br>
  <b>Option 3:</b><br>
  <input  class="inp-form"type="Text" name="opt3" size="30" required>
  <br>
  <b>Option 4:</b><br>
  <input class="inp-form" type="Text" name="opt4" size="30" required>
  <br>
  <b>Answer</b> (must be identical to correct option):<br>
  <input  class="inp-form" type="Text" name="answer" size="30" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class="form-submit" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Add" required>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: what you want looks a lot like a select2 implementation? : http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: @sarincm99  To which dropdown u want to show answer? U want to show option(1,2,3,4) value to dropdown?

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar sorry i entered a wrong code,in above code answer is displayed in text box,i want to use a drop down menu instead of that text box,so that i can take value from text box of option 1 ...4 and display in dropdown menu...

Comment: @sarincm99 K see my answer. Say its ok or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add another class to options text box (i.e) `option` like below.

Add `onclick="AddQS()"` to submit button.

Add one dropdown box.

```
function AddQS() {
     $('#sltOptions').empty();
     $('.option').each(function() {
         $('#sltOptions').append('<option value = ' + $(this).attr('name') + '>' + $(this).val() + '</option>');
      });
  }

<------------------>
<input class="inp-form option" type="Text" name="opt1" size="30" required>
<------------------>
<input class="form-submit" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Add" onclick="AddQS()" required>
<------------------>
<select id="sltOptions">
</select>
```

Comment: thankyou very much sir,it works...i a new to jquery...so,if your never mind,plz give some explanation of code also..thank you again ....

Comment: Adding new class `option` to all options text box. Using this class we can take all text box value which contain 'options' as class. So to get value im using `$('.option').each(function()`, its like for loop but exactly not. So for each iteration i can get value of each textbox one by one using `$(this).val()` and im appending this `<option>$(this).val()</option>` to bropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/47/

```
$('.options').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val().trim();
        $("#answer").append("<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>");        
});
```

Let me know is this example full fill your requirement or not.

Comment: thank you very much,this is exactly what i needed...thankyou again..sorry i dont have reputation to vote up your comment:(